# An error occurred while fetching Certbot snap plugins

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot, snap

An error occurred while fetching Certbot snap plugins: make sure the snapd service is running. An unexpected error occurred: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after some search, problem solved. the answer from certbot with some modifications.

1. check snap version and inspect the output

```
snap version
```

2. if output shows some issues, then restart snapd

```
service snapd restart
```

3. then recheck snap and certbot are working or not
4. if not, reinstall snap

> https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snapd